# Method area of java and stack area

Tags: java

I want to know what is the difference between method area and stack area as both works on methods... as far as I can understand method area stores code of instance method and stack area serialize their invocation am I right?

Comment: What do you mean by storing methods?  I'm confused about your question.

Comment: This answers what method area means, http://javapapers.com/core-java/java-jvm-memory-types/

Comment: Have you read [the official docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-2.html)?

Comment: *"in java stores methods by creating frames. And there is also a concept of method area in JAVA for storing methods. So, I am confused between the two..."*  Tip.  It is neither 'java' nor 'JAVA' but.. 'Java'.

Answer (score 4):

In Java Memory is divided into 3 parts:

1. Method Area
2. Heap
3. Stack

---

1. Method Area is memory where class is loaded and along with that static variables and constants are defined.
2. Stack is memory area where a method is loaded and its execution take place. All Local variables are stored in these.
3. Heap is that memory where objects are created , I mean where instance variables are created under object name.

Answer (score 1):

The method area every class bytecode is loaded and stored.
It means given class static and instance variable declaration statements, blocks, method, and constructors logic will be stored in the method area.
All static variable memory is allocated in this runtime area.